# WNetAddConnection2 failed (LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS) using account POLIFORMA\Administrator (0000052e)

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012

I tried to install a sccmclient on a windows 7 VM. I got this error:

[image]

Recently I have changed my password and I have a hunch that is the problem. I searched for the place where the administrator account can be changed in SCCM, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I readded my administrator account to the client push accounts:

[image]

[image]

That solved my problem. CCMsetup.exe was now running on the client.